# Scenario's for loseing messages with akka when all actors run in the same jvm

Tags: java, akka

I once wrote a multiplayer game in java with the help of the akka framwork. With their 'at-least-once' delivery I always wondered in which cases a message can get lost if all the `akka` actors are running in the same local jvm.

The design of the game was like a giant state machine (as events needed to be processed in order), so most of the times only 1 message was on it's way between all the involved actors. (Running multiple session in parralel was possible)

I have read that the communication of actors, when running locally, is done in-memory. So not considering out of memory error's, are their other (preferably reroducable) scenario's where messages are actually lost?

Note:
Message box manipulation is also not what I am looking for. Just legit cases where something goes wrong and the message is really lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have read that the communication of actors, when running locally, is done in-memory. So not considering out of memory error's, are their other (preferably reroducable) scenario's where messages are actually lost?

So, normally in-memory delivery is true, but you also specified that you are talking about the "at-least-once delivery" feature. And the docs ( https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/persistence.html#at-least-once-delivery ) specifically talk about how at-least-once changes a lot of the normal behavior. Specifically, at-least-once uses persistence to track what has been sent and what has been acknowledged.

So, when you are using at-least-once, there is a whole dance that has to happen when sending a message. First the message has to to be stored such that if the sending actor fails, that work can resume elsewhere. Second, the message has to be sent. Third, any response has to be correlated with the sent message and the receipt persisted so that if the actor fails after that point that the resuming actor knows that the message doesn't have to be retried.

Because of this, there should be no case where a message is lost. Even when a JVM is lost. (Even when all JVM's are lost.) That, after all is the point of "at-least-once", that the message is guaranteed to be delivered (and replied to). However, note that this does come with tradeoffs. (See the docs for the tradeoffs, although one obvious one is performance.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As far as I understand only the 2nd part "the message has to be sent" (including resent's) is done by akka, the rest I need to implement. ------ On another note: Are you aware of scenario's for the 'at-most-once' delivery? So thats an extra question - so I could just open another one.

Comment: No, akka does all of the work for you regarding guaranteed delivery. (Well, it does if you implement the required APIs.) I need to clean up my answer a bit, I wrote it quickly and I glossed over some of the details of the "dance". But it's all in the docs I link.

Comment: Maybe I am just misundertanding the docs. The 2nd Paragrah (when using the link provided by you) states  "... The AtLeastOnceDelivery traitAbstractPersistentActorWithAtLeastOnceDelivery class does not persist anything by itself. It is your responsibility to persist the intent that a message is sent and that a confirmation has been received."

Comment: And regarding your question regarding "at-most-one" almost all scenarios are better served by "at-most-once". It's probably easiest to just point you to the Akka docs on the subject: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/message-delivery-reliability.html .

Comment: Regarding misunderstanding the docs, I did say "if you implement the APIs". Akka does the work if persisting the state (indicating that the message is sent), dealing with recovery (including stashing and preventing overload), dealing with retries, correlating the deliveryId, etc., but you are going to have to implement the methods for updateState, receiveCommand, etc.

Comment: I've read the docs in the past and I still did not fully understand whether the error's mentioned under 'Reliability of Local Message Sends' are really all the possible sources. If my application runs into any Error i just go with erlangs 'let it fail' principle, so I still wanted to avoid potential message loss which would causes inconsistent states. So going for 'at-least-once' might have been just busywork on my side.